# In SQL Server, is there a way to get a single value from an identity column and repeatedly use it in the same scope?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, select

It's kind of hard to word the question in the title.  Let's say you have a table called Users, and let's say it has an identity / primary key column called "Id".  Let's say you want to, in the same transaction, get what you know will only be one instance of Id that falls within a fairly specific WHERE clause or something, then recycle it repeatedly in a very lengthy SELECT statement that's executed immediately afterwards.  Can this be done in SQL Server?  Basically what I'm trying to avoid is something like the following:

```
Dim id As Int32 = DBA.OneTimeQuery("SELECT Id FROM users <where clause>").Rows(0)(0)
Return DBA.OneTimeQuery("SELECT <a lot of different things, involving multiple sub
    -selects that have to pull from the variable id>")
'DBA.OneTimeQuery returns a DataTable
```

I know I can avoid using two different connections or whatever by recycling the first where clause, but it's pretty wasteful to have even the same connection and transaction keep re-finding the same exact piece of information.

I want to avoid having Sql Server search for that single value from the Id column more than once, and I also want to be able to put it in the same Sql transaction and connection.  How can this be done?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing this in VB or a stored proc?

Comment: I'm curious . . . why do you care if the SELECTs are executed in a single transaction?

Comment: Let's not say "let's say" so many times.

Comment: @Blam Let's say we do as you ask; what do we say, instead? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber And I tied an edit.

Comment: @Jordan Kaye: I could go either way.

Comment: @AndrewBarber my edits got rolled back.

Comment: @Blam Panzer was editing the post himself. Oh, nevermind... I see he literally just rolled back. Hmph... Panzer; Blam's edit really made your question easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this within a stored procedure.
You store the ID in the variable and use it when you need it:

```
DECLARE @MyID int

SET @MyID = (SELECT SomeID FROM MyUsers WHERE ... )

--now use @MyID

SELECT Foo.Bar, Foo.Rascal FROM MyTable WHERE UserID = @MyID
```

Comment: You might want to enforce a single transaction since that seems important to him.

Comment: @JordanKaye - It is possible, feel free to edit to meet needs, this is a collaborative site.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you perform a join?

```
SELECT <Lengthy listing> 
FROM <Some Table> INNER JOIN Users 
ON <Some Property from Some table> = Users.Id 
WHERE <Your filter clause over the Users table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a SQL Variable?

I've buuilt lengty scripts where I first insert a new record, store the inserted ID into a variable, and just reuse the variable throughout the rest of the code.

```
DECLARE @insertedID int;
INSERT INTO table1 ();

SET @insertedID = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO table2 (table1ID) VALUES (@insertedID);
INSERT INTO table3 (table1ID) VALUES (@insertedID);
```

etc.